# Expressing similarity in a single sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

I want to express similarity in a single sentence, e.g.,

- *"Oil to the car is that of food to our body"*
- *"words from his mouth is equal to sword to the enemy"*

I remember there is a pattern somewhat like above but I cannot remember clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first example,

> Oil to the car is that of food to our body.

The nearest grammatical and idiomatic expression I can think of is

> Oil is to the car what food is to the body.

For the second example,

> words from his mouth is equal to sword to the enemy

I'm not sure what you are referring to; maybe

> He uses his words like a sword.